# No webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById and SetAttribute in XAML C# Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, web, windows-store-apps, bots

I want to control the web browser in xaml c# windows 8 store app 
however i cannot see the methods
the one i used for form applications in c# is given below

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("xxxx"))
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", "admin");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", "password1");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
            }
}
```

how can i use the same functions in windows 8 xaml c# store apps?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
webView1.InvokeScript(
    "eval",
    new string[] { "document.getElementById('login').value = 'admin';" });
webView1.InvokeScript(
    "eval",
    new string[] { "document.getElementById('pass').value = 'password';" });
webView1.InvokeScript(
    "eval",
    new string[] { "document.getElementById('submit').click();" });
```